# can't concatenate strings with quotes

Tags: php, oracle

Good evening to everyone,

Sorry if my question apperes sily but I'm pazzled by my very trivial problem

In one of the pages of my project I can't concatenate a string containing ' signs

this string can't be concatenated:

```
$stidR = "INSERT INTO rec_ret_info VALUES('".$rrcode."', ".$modnum.", '".$sdate."', '".$venue."', ".$fac.", ".$date.", ".$sem.")";
```

but this can:

```
$stidR = "INSERT INTO rec_ret_info VALUES(".$rrcode.", ".$modnum.", ".$sdate.", ".$venue.", ".$fac.", ".$date.", ".$sem.")";
```

Apparently if I remove ' signs it works. But i really need them. I really don't know where is the problem. Would be gratefull if you can point me on it.

Comment: Define, what is "it's not working"? Error from MySQL? Wrong data inserted? Or what?

Comment: Please don't do this if you value your sanity. Please read this: http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: i can see date data without quotes ...

Comment: first query doesn't work for database. When I tried to output the string it's not outputing

Comment: what column types are?

Comment: columns with quotes are varchar and date. thats why I'm putting them in quotes

Comment: Not working is the value is not adding value in database. no Error is prompted. I tried to see the string by outputing it, but there is no output if a string has '

Comment: Using prepared statements would fix your error and make sure you don't get hacked using SQL Injection. You might wanna consider doing that.

Comment: what are the prepared statements?

Comment: We still dont have any error! Please show the actual PHP error or response from mysqli_error().

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a prepared statement to bind a variable?

Connection to Oracle with PDO - [More information!](http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/how-to-connect-to-the-oracle-using-pdo/)

**Update**

PDO Prepared Statement as an example. The only thing you need to change is the query structure if Oracle is different to MySql in that regard. The binding of variables and the execution will work the same :)

```
$queryString= "INSERT INTO tablename (ColumnName1,ColumnName2,ColumnName3,ColumnName4,ColumnName5,ColumnName6,ColumnName7) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$query = $db->prepare($queryString);
$query->bindValue(1, $variable1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(2, $variable2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(3, $variable3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(4, $variable4, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(5, $variable5, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(6, $variable6, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(7, $variable7, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
```

Comment: Might want to update your question as it's tagged as MySql but not oracle :) You can use PDO with Oracle [Here is some information](http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/how-to-connect-to-the-oracle-using-pdo/).

Comment: Also, I have updated my answer. Dunno if it will be helpful for you, but that prepared statement will work perfectly fine with Oracle. Might just need to change the query structure.

Answer (score 0):

simply make `echo` of your statement like
`echo $stidR ;` and check the resulting sql, and see what you are doing wrong